# Code Igniter Browser Cookie Expired but not deleted?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I'm using Code Igniter and created a cookie using:

```
<?php
$cookie = array(
            'name'   => $cookie_name,
            'value'  => $cookie_value,
            'expire' => COOKIE_1_MIN, // value is '60'
            'domain' => '',
            'path'   => '/',
            'secure' => TRUE
);
$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
?>
```

As far as I remember, when the cookie's time expired in the browser then it will be automatically deleted in the browser? Am I correct?

Because right now the expired cookie that I created is still in the browser and was not deleted.

Below is my Cookie info in Firefox:

```
is_logged_in=1; expires=Thu, 23 May 2013 21:50:09 GMT; path=/; domain=localhost; Secure
```

Thanks.

Kind Regards,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

The expired cookies not being used by the browser, that's why they are not accessible by the website or by JavaScript.
They supposed to get deleted when opened the website they are belong to and only if that website doesn't update them. That's why some cookies never get expired even if you set them to expire at the end of session - the website re-sets them with new date.

Read This You will get your answer

[HTTP Cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age)